# Executable not running correctly after being called from a VBA Excel Macro

Tags: excel, vba, macros, exe

I have an executable "Operate.exe" which reads data from a text file "Weightings.txt" and performs some operations on it. This runs fine when executed independently.

I'm trying to execute this from a button in excel using VBA. The program runs, but "weightings.txt" is not being open/found.

This is the code I'm using in VBA:

```
Sub TextBox1_Click()
Shell ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Operate.exe", vbNormalFocus
End Sub
```

The folder contains Operate.exe, Operate.pdb, Game.xlsm and Weightings.txt.

Is Weightings.txt not being found because the exe program is being run from VBA?

Comment: The current working directory when you run the program from the script might not be the same as when you run from a console. Try printing the current working directory to check.

Comment: Thanks. This makes sense. Need to learn more about directories

Answer (score 0):

Change the current default working directory to the ThisWorkbook.Path.

```
Sub TextBox1_Click()
    Debug.Print CurDir
    ChDir ThisWorkbook.Path
    Debug.Print CurDir
    Shell ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Operate.exe", vbNormalFocus
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly.